# Is there a simple tool to download/install and upgrade Node.JS?

Tags: node.js, express

As the title, I would like to use a simple tool that help me to download/install and check new versions for Node.JS,I also would like to install more then one version to test my applications with different engine.

Is there a tool like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Node (version, binary, virtual) environments:

1. https://github.com/visionmedia/n
2. https://github.com/creationix/nvm
3. https://github.com/isaacs/nave

Answer (score 2):

NVM is exactly what you need: http://github.com/creationix/nvm

Answer (score 1):

Try nodeenv. It is brilliant https://github.com/ekalinin/nodeenv